# regex conflict phone number and postal code

Tags: regex, postal-code

I want to extract a postal code from a blob of text.
My postal code is six digits long and can be `560011` or `560 011`. I have used regex (`/[0-9]{3}[ ]?[0-9]{3}/`), but this also captures the first 6 digits of my phone number. I tried using `[^0-9]` after my 6<sup>th</sup> digit, but this captures the next char too. How can I capture only the postal code, neglecting any number more than 6 digits?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is to add word boundaries. Like

```
/\b[0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3}\b/
```

or

```
/\b\d{3} ?\d{3}\b/
```

if your regex flavor supports the *digit* character class.

The word boundary - `\b` only matches if the character before and after it are *from different classes*, or rather - one is of the *word* character class, and the other isn't. The *word character class* includes digits, so adding `\b` before and after your regex, makes it match only if the number is preceded and followed by a non digit (*word character*).

Also, to have a character class with just one character (the `[ ]`) doesn't make any sense. It's the same as just have the character in the regex.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jB7eB0/1).

Comment: Thank you! just what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parenthesis to capture the first six numerics, ignoring the subsequent non-numeric:

```
/([0-9]{3} ?[0-9]{3})[^0-9]/
```

This matches 123456 and 123 456 but not 1234567.